# Access resource string by string name in array

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a resource from XML using an array of strings because it's currently in a loop.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this?

The resource name is the same name as the array string name just to be clear.

So far I have tried:

```
mMainEngine.mContext.getString(R.string.class.getField(Modification.ModicationNames[Current]).getInt(null)),
```

Comment: you have the name of a resource and you want to get its id?

Comment: The resource name is the same as the array string name

Comment: you need [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not missunderstood you

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("name_of_resource","string", getPackageName());
```

is what you neeed

Comment: The method getPackageName() is undefined for the type ModificationContainer

Comment: you need a context. is ModificationContainer an activity?

Comment: The error is "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0" but the string defiantly exists.

Comment: put string instead of id. See my edit. getIdentifier("name_of_resource","string", getPackageName());

Answer (score 0):

Just for example I am accessing Drawable. You can get id from name as follows

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
String strpckg = context.getPackageName();

int id = res.getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", strpckg);
```

further you can access Drawable as :

```
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(id);
```

Comment: This is for drawable you can do same for String or any resource that you want