# Android: how to parameterize which resource to use at runtime?

Tags: android, algorithm, reflection, android-resources

Think about a list of parameters and their respective intervals of discrete integer values:

```
a[1-N], b[1-M], c[1-K], d[1-J]
```

a, b, c, d are the variables while between square brackets there are intervals of their possible values.

At runtime if they are

```
a=1, b=2, c=3, d=5
```

then I'd like to get the resource with

```
name = R.string.string_1_2_3_5
```

Is it possible?
I wouldn't want to make a series of cascade switches for each variable to finally pick a resource. I know this could work but is there another way?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732945/access-resource-string-by-string-name-in-array). Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: I'm going to try, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java reflection like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821330/5166645).

If you need to retrieve strings like that more than once, in order to get fast access, you should first construct a hashtable with the field names of R.string as keys (maybe when you launch the app).